# www subdomain not working on AWS

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, ssl

I am hosting this site https://whitewaterwriters.com/ on an AWS instance.

I'd like the url https://www.whitewaterwriters.com/ to work as well, but it doesn't.

I understand that this happens in a 'hosted zone' in AWS. Here's my hosted zone:

[image]

...and I understand that I have put in the subdomain redirection properly.

I run a test and get:

[image]

which suggests that I'm on the right lines.

It's possible that the issue is that I don't have a TLS cert for  https://www.whitewaterwriters.com/  yet, but I can't get one of those without the domain being visible, and my nginx doesn't allow it, so I've altered my nginx.conf to

```
   server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  www.whitewaterwriters.com;
        location /{
                root /usr/share/nginx/html/whitewaterwriters-site/_site/;
        }

    }


    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  whitewaterwriters.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

so that http://www.whitewaterwriters.com/ should at least work without the https, but no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I've now added an a-record as well:

[image]

Comment: You have a NS record for `www.whitewaterwriters.com`. You don't want that. You want an A record for it.

Comment: To check - do I want both or just one? (and will add content)

Comment: You want one set of `NS` records, for the non-www. Leave that alone (it's the one AWS added for you). Keep the A record for the non-www. Create a new A record for the www version, pointing to the same IP as the non-www. Remove the NS record for the www version.

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem (along with some faff in the nginx config) feel free to make it an answer.

Comment: You can also create a CNAME record for www. That results in an extra DNS lookup though. @ceejayoz maybe convert your comment to an answer so the question can be closed off?